# Angular 2 Hello world example stuck at Loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a simple Angular 2 Hello World example using npm as the package manager. but i cant get it to run. Here is the code I am using

[image: Folder Structure]

[image: SystemJS.Config.JS]

[image: app.component.ts]

[image: app.module.ts]

[image: main.ts]

[image: index.html]

This is copied from a book line by line. Not sure what is going wrong here. The browser is stuck at Loading...
NPM window shows 404 for /main.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better to add code instead of inserting images

Comment: Did you checked in console, Is there any error msg?. If is is please take a screen shot of error message and update.